# @IntegrationTest in spring boot makes concordion tests fail when run in combination with 'normal' unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am using concordion for end to end testing my spring boot REST API.
I found that i could let the concordion test start up my spring application with the @IntegrationTest annotation. This works if i manually run 1 concorion test, or all concordion test.. But if i include regular unit test (without the @IntegrationTest), then the concordion tests will fail with an `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/myrestservice":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.`

If i annotate my regular unit tests with the @IntegrationTest annotation, it all works. But i would like to know if anyone knows a better way?

edit:
both my concordion tests and my unit tests have the following other annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = Application.class,
    loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a cached `ApplicationContext` shared across all your tests. You can change the cache key by changing the configuration sources (e.g. add an empty `TestConfiguration.class`) or by using a profile (e.g. `@ActiveProfiles("integration")).